# Get specific repeated part in txt file using re module

Tags: python

how can i copy repeated paragraph in text file start and end with specific words using re module and insert each paragraph in index of list

paragraph example

```
RemoteConfig cleanup.txt --prefix  /tftpboot/sites --status  /tftpboot/190315_140116/cleanup/stat_KSHA500 --conf /export/home-V cisco -N -S -o -P telnet,ssh2
RemoteConfig cleanup.txt --prefix  /tftpboot/sites --status  /tftpboot/190315_140200/cleanup/stat_KSHA11 --conf /export/home-V cisco -N -S -o -P telnet,ssh2
RemoteConfig cleanup.txt --prefix  /tftpboot/sites --status  /tftpboot/190315_1500/cleanup/stat_KSHA211 --conf /export/home-V cisco -N -S -o -P telnet,ssh2
```

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what you mean. What is your expected or desired output?

Comment: need output of list each index have line start with remoteconfig and end with ssh2 using re

Comment: Hope my solution helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Language barriers aside, based on your criteria try this

```
>>> import re

>>> string = '''RemoteConfig cleanup.txt --prefix  /tftpboot/sites --status  /tftpboot/190315_140116/cleanup/stat_KSHA500 --conf /export/home-V cisco -N -S -o -P telnet,ssh2
RemoteConfig cleanup.txt --prefix  /tftpboot/sites --status  /tftpboot/190315_140200/cleanup/stat_KSHA11 --conf /export/home-V cisco -N -S -o -P telnet,ssh2
RemoteConfig cleanup.txt --prefix  /tftpboot/sites --status  /tftpboot/190315_1500/cleanup/stat_KSHA211 --conf /export/home-V cisco -N -S -o -P telnet,ssh2'''


>>> configs = re.findall('(?i)RemoteConfig[\S\s]*?ssh2(?=\s|$)', string)


>>> for config in configs:
        print(config)

#Output
RemoteConfig cleanup.txt --prefix  /tftpboot/sites --status  /tftpboot/190315_140116/cleanup/stat_KSHA500 --conf /export/home-V cisco -N -S -o -P telnet,ssh2
RemoteConfig cleanup.txt --prefix  /tftpboot/sites --status  /tftpboot/190315_140200/cleanup/stat_KSHA11 --conf /export/home-V cisco -N -S -o -P telnet,ssh2
RemoteConfig cleanup.txt --prefix  /tftpboot/sites --status  /tftpboot/190315_1500/cleanup/stat_KSHA211 --conf /export/home-V cisco -N -S -o -P telnet,ssh2




>>> configs

#Output
['RemoteConfig cleanup.txt --prefix  /tftpboot/sites --status  /tftpboot/190315_140116/cleanup/stat_KSHA500 --conf /export/home-V cisco -N -S -o -P telnet,ssh2', 'RemoteConfig cleanup.txt --prefix  /tftpboot/sites --status  /tftpboot/190315_140200/cleanup/stat_KSHA11 --conf /export/home-V cisco -N -S -o -P telnet,ssh2', 'RemoteConfig cleanup.txt --prefix  /tftpboot/sites --status  /tftpboot/190315_1500/cleanup/stat_KSHA211 --conf /export/home-V cisco -N -S -o -P telnet,ssh2']
```